# Trace $stdout/$stderr in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to test the output of my gem that is using [GLI](http://naildrivin5.com/gli/) however I'm running into issues. In my test setup I'm redirecting `$stdout` and `$stderr` to `StringIO` instances however when I run my code I'm still getting a message printed to my screen rather than being redirected to my custom objects.

```
begin
  old_stdout, old_stderr, $stdout, $stderr = $stdout, $stderr, StringIO.new, StringIO.new

  @exit_code = described_class.run([command] + command_args)
  @stdout = $stdout.string
  @stderr = $stderr.string
ensure
  $stdout = old_stdout
  $stderror = old_stderr
end
```

I would expect that `described_class.run([command] + command_args)` which ends up calling GLI's `exit_now!` method would be redirected to `$stderr` however this does not seem to be the case.

Is there a way to "trace" where/how a string was printed to the screen?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] of the problem you're describing? What values for `described_class`, `command` and `command_args` can I use to replicate the problem as you describe it? I took a quick look at [the `GLI` source code](https://github.com/davetron5000/gli/blob/84c21131320168178077e9bfe03f51f0e28d361e/lib/gli/app_support.rb#L242), and I can't see why your approach would fail, under normal circumstances.

Comment: However, I also noticed that the library provides an [`error_device=`](https://github.com/davetron5000/gli/blob/84c21131320168178077e9bfe03f51f0e28d361e/lib/gli/app_support.rb#L5-L7) method, which is used internally for its own tests such as [here](https://github.com/davetron5000/gli/blob/84c21131320168178077e9bfe03f51f0e28d361e/test/tc_subcommand_parsing.rb#L8-L23). Could that approach be of use?

Comment: You can still access the original streams using the constants `STDOUT/STDERR`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using RSpec based on `described_class`. If you're just trying to test `stdout`/`stderr`, then there's a matcher for that.

```
it "does something" do 
  expect { 
    described_class.run([command] + command_args) 
  }.to output(/some string match/).to_stdout
end
```

The owner of the GLI project made some suggestions [here](https://github.com/davetron5000/gli/issues/221) about how to test GLI setup, perhaps that will help as well.